# How to fix Django regular expression problem

Tags: django, regex, url-pattern

Django Rest Framework after User registration sends out an email for the new User to verify the email address.
The link attached is like:

`https://my_domain.com/api/verify_email/?token=ddfddjrf....fddkfjdjh`

My *api.urls.py* file looks like:

```
api.urls.py
from django.urls import re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   re_path(r'^verify_email/(?P<token>[\w.-]+)/',views.verify_email, name="verify_email"),
[
```

And in project *urls.py*

```
...
path('api/', include("api.urls")),
...
```

When I try to run that link I get:

Page not found (404)
The current path api/verify_email/, didn't match any of these.

I can see a URL pattern from the URL.conf:
Django tried these URL patterns,in this order.

```
...    
api/ ^verify_email/(?P<token>[\w.-]+)/ [name='verify_email']    
...
```

I hope somebody can help because I can't find a solution somewhere ....
And I tried several things to fix it. But without any success.
Thank's a lot.

Greetings RR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, it is lacking the token, so you visit it with:

```
/api/verify_email/ddfddjrf....fddkfjdjh/
```

not as part of the *querystring*.

Comment: Hello, thank you! 
My link is .... /api/verify_email/?token= .....

so sorry but I can't follow your answer.

Comment: @AxelSiebert: you can, just change the email template. Personally i think if a parameter is required, passing it as querystring is a very bad idea, because querystrings are a bit *too* dynamic.

Comment: OK  gotcha! It works without the token query. I'll change the email template. Thank you very much!